# how do i set length of message queue for subscriber in rosjava?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rosjava we don’t have access to set message queue on subscriber. So rosjava node is not receiving & executing messages in realtime. So anybody here has any workaround to resolve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203431/how-do-i-set-length-of-message-queue-for-subscriber-in-rosjava?/) by [stark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20255/stark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Kircheis answered in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/74509/sending-subsequent-messages-in-rosjava-leads-to-message-loss-solved/), you can set the message queue size when you add a message listener to your subscriber.

The rosjava Listener.java tutorial creates a listener like this:

```
Subscriber<std_msgs.String> subscriber = connectedNode.newSubscriber("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
subscriber.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<std_msgs.String>() {
  @Override
  public void onNewMessage(std_msgs.String message) {
    log.info("I heard: \"" + message.getData() + "\"");
  }
});
```

When adding the message listener, you can specify a queue size:

```
int queueSize = 10;
subscriber.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<std_msgs.String>() {
  @Override
  public void onNewMessage(std_msgs.String message) {
    log.info("I heard: \"" + message.getData() + "\"");
  }
}, queueSize);
```

If you do not specify a queue size, the default size is 1.

---

Originally posted by [grieneis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3243/grieneis/) with karma: 16 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0